# Regex in python window.*} where * implies wildcard character

Tags: python, regex

I have a huge string and need to remove every occurrence of `window.*}` from it, where `*` is wild-card that selects everything.

I am using following regex

```
data=re.sub("window.*?\}","",data)
```

`data` contains the provided sample data

However the problem is it replacing entire chunk between first `window` and last `}`. As you can see i have used *? for non greedy match, but still not working.

I need to remove all functions like window.onload, etc. from string

Sample data as follows:

```
</td><td>Care Instructions</td><td></td><td>Tested</td><td></td><td>Maintenance</td><td></td><td>Lightweight</td><td></td><td>Water resistance</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>3358</td><td>2012-12-18 11:09:21</td><td>5589043</td><td>UNPublished</td><td>SNK-300-SNORKEL</td><td>0</td><td>Tribord</td><td>542</td><td>433</td><td>14.5</td><td>Adult</td><td>any</td><td>window.onload = function(){window.parent.CKEDITOR._["contentDomReadyattribute85"]( window );}</td><td>
    snorkelers and scuba divers.
</td><td>window.onload = function(){window.parent.CKEDITOR._["contentDomReadyattribute111"]( window );}</td><td>2</td><td></td><td>FALSE</td><td>5000</td><td>128</td><td>MASKS & SNORKELS</td><td>11</td><td>Diving</td><td>519713</td><td>White</td><td></td><td>http://test.com/image/products/p_3358/zoom_asset_7454285.jpg</td><td>Freedom of movement</td><td>
    Soft hypollergenic black silicone mouthpiece.
</td><td>Maintenance</td><td></td><td>Reduced chafing</td><td>
    100% phthalate-free PVC tube, 100% silicone mouthpiece.
</td><td>Technical</td><td></td><td>Easy storage</td><td>
    Flexible tube that can positioned between mask strap and forehead.


</td><td>Composition</td><td>
    salt water resistant. Only rinse with fresh water before prolonged storage.
</td><td>Comfortable</td><td>
    Soft hypollergenic black silicone mouthpiece.
</td><td>Easy breathing</td><td></td><td>Anatomic design</td><td>
    Flexible tube that can positioned between mask strap and forehead.


</td><td>Care Instructions</td><td>
    salt water resistant. Only rinse with fresh water before prolonged storage.
</td><td>Mouth piece</td><td></td><td>Restriction of use</td><td></td><td>http://test.com/image/products/p_3358/zoom_asset_33225717.jpg</td><td>http://test.com/image/products/p_3358/zoom_asset_30448342.jpg</td><td>http://test.com/image/products/p_3358/zoom_asset_19099347.jpg</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>3359</td><td>2014-01-09 18:32:31</td><td>8174997</td><td>Published</td><td>DYNAMO-LAMP</td><td>90</td><td>Tribord</td><td>999</td><td>649</td><td>14.5</td><td>Any</td><td>any</td><td></td><td>
    Snorkelling.Watertight to 5m, eco-friendly and economical.
</td><td></td><td>2</td><td></td><td>FALSE</td><td>333.7</td><td>129</td><td>SNORKELING KITS</td><td>11</td><td>Diving</td><td>1349256</td><td>Black</td><td></td><td>http://test.com/image/products/p_3359/big_800PX_29672977a.jpg</td><td>Battery</td><td>
    3 modes: Blinking, eco-friendly, and 100% (100% = 10minutes after 1min charge)
</td><td>Features</td><td></td><td>Swimming Depth</td><td>
```

Comment: Please give a complete example including sample data with expected output.

Comment: Use a raw string: `r"window.*?\}"` for strings (esp. REs) containing a \

Comment: RE does not contain \, i have escaped }. I just need to delete everything that is between each windows. and } including them.

Comment: For eg. I want to delete all codes in that html --> window.onload = function(){window.parent.CKEDITOR._["contentDomReadyattribute111"]( window );}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'window[^}]*}')
subst = ""
result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wZ0iA3/2